# Python pandas error

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pandas, indexing

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('inputfile.txt',names=['chr','start','stop','gene','strand'], delimiter=r'\s+') 
print(df1)
count =0
c = 0
for i in df1:
    for y in df1:
        if abs(df1.loc[i,"start"]- df1.loc[y,"stop"]) < 201:
            if i != y:
                index
                c +=1
print(c)
```

I have a sample input file:

```
chr15   74436458    74466677    pi-1700016M24Rik.1  -
chr17   79734018    79754230    pi-Cdc42ep3.1   -
chr3    124103907   124128909   pi-1700006A11Rik.1  -
chr5    102261978   102280532   pi-Wdfy3.1  -
chr6    85061409    85076088    pi-Gm5878.1 -
chr9    51573456    51661164    pi-Arhgap20.1   +
chr10   127114107   127132221   pi-Tmem194.1    +
chr11   103286577   103315010   11-qE1-9443.1   +
chr11   107855325   107859037   11-qE1-3997.1   +
chr11   108278889   108286739   11-qE1-252.1    -
chr12   99620581    99658258    12-qE-23911.1   -
chr12   99658453    99692927    12-qE-7089.1    +
chr13   21595489    21598393    13-qA3.1-213.1  -
chr13   24997468    25026901    13-qA3.1-355.1  +
chr1    94888921    94893644    1-qD-4525.1 -
chr13   50363393    50412729    13-qA5-208.1    +
chr13   50607591    50690856    13-qA5-464.1    -
chr13   51001008    51029517    13-qA5-703.1    -
chr13   52192103    52219527    13-qA5-967.1    +
chr13   53489036    53549907    13-qB1-1517.1   +
chr14   20445381    20472632    14-qA3-3095.1   -
chr14   24901215    24939690    14-qA3-19970.1  +
chr14   25184829    25189036    14-qA3-2286.1   -
chr14   25244385    25249047    14-qA3-284.1    -
chr14   45377787    45409614    14-qC1-1261.1   -
chr14   45546497    45569941    14-qC1-1010.1   +
chr15   59081442    59106777    15-qD1-17920.1  -
chr15   59106921    59123501    15-qD1-4001.1   +
chr15   74466817    74478882    15-qD3-14639.1  +
chr15   78483658    78500962    15-qE1-8387.1   -
chr15   79758435    79764840    15-qE1-1119.1   +
chr1    127071468   127074556   1-qE3-706.1 +
chr17   22634368    22656090    17-qA3.3-352.1  +
chr17   27425220    27461973    17-qA3.3-27363.1    -
chr17   27462141    27504428    17-qA3.3-26735.1    +
chr17   49251595    49252836    17-qC-935.1 -
chr17   50378485    50382342    17-qC-59.1  +
chr17   66556151    66581098    17-qE1.1-7037.1 +
chr18   67189100    67226114    18-qE1-36451.1  -
chr18   67226241    67241315    18-qE1-1295.1   +
chr19   37333596    37338356    19-qC2-1361.1   -
chr2    92381298    92439234    2-qE1-35981.1   +
chr2    127517589   127529447   2-qF1-2536.1    +
chr2    150953183   150984330   2-qG3-1029.1    +
chr3    20301593    20405121    3-qA2-617.1 -
chr3    34725552    34777871    3-qA3-2052.1    +
chr4    57373062    57377138    4-qB3-3994.1    -
chr4    61881631    61891970    4-qB3-639.1 -
chr4    61892039    61900375    4-qB3-277.1 +
chr4    93946842    93998314    4-qC5-17839.1   -
chr4    123510867   123519209   4-qD2.2-2182.1  -
chr4    123571373   123573843   4-qD2.2-349.1   -
chr4    135182710   135186113   4-qD3-2082.1    +
chr5    113752221   113769115   5-qF-14508.1    -
chr5    113769157   113794752   5-qF-14224.1    +
chr5    115284179   115303596   5-qF-4633.1 -
chr5    137395015   137412982   5-qG2-950.1 +
chr5    144519247   144527999   5-qG2-2301.1    +
chr5    150592651   150627915   5-qG3-23659.1   -
chr6    81843811    81860488    6-qC3-6258.1    -
chr6    83525934    83538118    6-qC3-100.1 +
chr6    85937105    85953600    6-qC3-2394.1    -
chr6    87932334    87944161    6-qD1-2831.1    -
chr10   18516611    18551736    10-qA3-2592.1   -
chr6    127726093   127746390   6-qF3-8009.1    -
chr6    127746448   127791908   6-qF3-28913.1   +
chr7    60142976    60169237    7-qB5-6255.1    +
chr7    77019095    77054469    7-qD1-9417.1    -
chr7    77054649    77111245    7-qD1-16444.1   +
chr7    80242711    80250159    7-qD1-654.1 -
chr7    80250197    80271441    7-qD1-19431.1   +
chr7    80926316    80961355    7-qD2-24830.1   -
chr1    57405819    57434364    1-qC1.3-637.1   -
chr7    80961480    80977906    7-qD2-11976.1   +
chr7    132476266   132493286   7-qF3-3125.1    -
chr7    132493384   132508334   7-qF3-246.1 +
chr10   20030311    20032118    10-qA3-143.1    -
chr8    28403548    28406760    8-qA2-343.1 -
chr8    38155119    38158009    8-qA4-332.1 -
chr8    38166951    38168562    8-qA4-155.1 -
chr8    94713358    94718315    8-qC5-8200.1    +
chr8    95933840    95951276    8-qC5-2209.1    -
chr8    112641565   112656356   8-qE1-3748.1    +
chr9    3184709 3199792 9-qA1-178.1 -
chr9    54054980    54097630    9-qA5.3-24188.1 -
chr9    54097752    54117106    9-qA5.3-1495.1  +
chr9    67539058    67581593    9-qC-31469.1    -
chr9    67581751    67608736    9-qC-10667.1    +
chr9    122711578   122714587   9-qF4-150.1 -
chr10   62114440    62164257    10-qB4-6488.1   +
chr10   66154778    66160884    10-qB5.1-5404.1 -
chr10   66161040    66171440    10-qB5.1-221.1  +
chr10   75300268    75324443    10-qC1-12816.1  +
chr10   83951038    83967582    10-qC1-117.1    +
chr10   85211306    85238346    10-qC1-2617.1   +
chr10   86011423    86054254    10-qC1-1527.1   -
chr10   86079756    86088620    10-qC1-875.1    +
chr10   94136457    94151187    10-qC2-545.1    -
chr11   50755203    50757227    11-qB1.3-590.1  -

column1=chr
column2=start
column3=end
column4=gene
column5=orientation
```

I am trying to find sites that have the same chromosome but have a difference of 200. This is what I have so far and keep on getting an error.

If someone can please keep. KeyError: 'the label [chr] is not in the [index]'

Answer (score 1):

The line `for i in df1` is actually iterating through the columns of your dataframe, not the rows, you want `for i in df1.index:`

By the way it's better do things in terms of vectorised operations on columns rather than iterating like this if you can, something like

```
import numpy as np
c = np.sum(np.abs(df['start'] - df['stop']) < 201)
```